# Does Indian with ECR passport and Dubai employment visa need clearance?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, uae, ecr

I lived in Africa for around 8 years and have an Emigration Check Required (ECR) on my Indian passport. I'm currently in India and have an employment visa for Dubai. Do I need emigration clearance or not?

Comment: Why wouldn't you?

Comment: Shouldn't this go to [Expatriates](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com)?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, by law, you do:

[**Bureau of Immigration India**](http://boi.gov.in/content/encrecr)

> **ENCR/ECR**
>
> As per the Emigration Act, 1983, Emigration Check Required (ECR) categories of Indian passport holders, require to obtain "Emigration Clearance" from the [office of Protector of Emigrants (POE)](http://boi.gov.in/content/poe-offices-india), Ministry of Overseas Indian Affairs for going to following 18 countries.
>
> United Arab Emirates (UAE), The Kingdom of Saudi Arabia (KSA), Qatar, Oman, Kuwait, Bahrain, Malaysia, Libya, Jordan, Yemen, Sudan, Afghanistan, Indonesia, Syria, Lebanon, Thailand, Iraq (emigration banned).
>
> However , the Ministry of Overseas Indian Affairs (Emigration Policy Division) have allowed ECR passport holders traveling abroad for purposes others than employment to leave the country on production of valid passport, valid visa and return ticket at the immigration counters at international airports in India w.e.f. 1st October 2007.
>
> POE clearance is required only when there is “Emigration Check Required” endorsement in the passport.